# send image behind text word using VBS

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

i'm using VBS to create a title screen and i have a problem trying to send a image behind te text.

**Here is my code:**

```
function page()
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\xxx.docx")
    objDoc.Sections.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = true
    Set head = objDoc.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\img.png")
    head.PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.7
    head.ZOrder msoSendBehindText 'I try to use msoSendToBack, SendBack, SendBehindText, Back and others and not work 
end function
```

i just want send "head" to the back , the actual result is the image is not in the back of text, and the version of word is 2013.

If someone, know how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the actual result? What is the Word version?

Comment: i just want send "head" to the back , the actual result is the image is not in the back of text, and the version of word is  2013

Comment: More importantly, why you using VBS and MS Word to build a Splash Screen? If you’re set on using VBScript you could do this with an [tag:hta] (HTML Application). Example of one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29581832/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart because i'm creating a evidence file, and i need call a function from UFT to send a PDF file

Comment: Thanks for not including [tag:hp-uft] and wasting 10 minutes of my life. Added the tag.

Comment: @Lankymart just calm down, my apologize

Comment: I was calm, more disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was, the utilization of numeration

```
head.ZOrder 5
```

https://bettersolutions.com/vba/enumerations/msozordercmd.htm

with this change, i solve my problem.